# VMware Workstation is not grabbing input on click

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm running VMware Workstation and I'm finding that the program is not grabbing mouse inputs on click or on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> input, both options are set to on in preferences.

If I manually connect either the mouse or keyboard to the VM (I.e. Connect (Disconnect From host)) it works fine, but obviously this isn't very convenient and I can only connect either the mouse or keyboard at a time.

Any ideas how I can get this to work? I know that VMware should be able to grab mouse inputs on click and that I should be able to grab focus back from the VM with ctrl+alt I just can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old; since this comes up in search results I feel a duty to answer.

Assuming you're on a mac, I found that this problem was caused by VMware not being granted accessibility permissions:

[image: Security and Privacy window on macOS > Privacy > Accessibility]

This can be found under System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility